# Chisel3 compare UInt bits every clock cycle [runlength encoder]

Tags: chisel

I am building a run length encoder module and I 've run into a problem.

The original bitstream is stored in memory as uint8: 11111100 -> 252, 00000110 -> 6 etc

I load each block of the original bitstream into a register `val in = Reg(UInt(8.W))` and then I want to compare the 1st bit against the 2nd and then the 2nd against the 3rd and so on, to calculate the run's length.
This is part of my state machine.

```
switch(state) {
  // code here ...
  is(step1) {
    logic.io.current_bit := in(7)
    logic.io.next_bit := in(6)
    // code here ...
  }
  is(step2) {
    current_bit := in(6)
    next_bit := in(5)
    // code here ...
  }
  // ... more steps ...
  is(step7) {
    current_bit := in(1)
    next_bit := in(0)
    // code here ...
  }
  // code here ...
}
```

I have a combinational circuit named logic that decides equality of two consecutive bits and if the next state is step n+1 or store the run's length.
I think there is a lot of code redundancy, but I cannot think another way.

Is there a way to input in(x) where x is a number defined in my state machine?

Any thoughts on how I could make this in a more elegant way?

---

**EDIT:**

*Module I/O:*

```
val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val valid = Input(Bool()) // enables-disables the module
    val mem_addr_load = Input(UInt(mem_addr_length.W)) // memory position to load the uints
    val mem_addr_store = Input(UInt(mem_addr_length.W)) // memory position to store the uints
    val mem_in = Input(UInt(8.W)) // uint input - loads 252 so it translates 11111100 bitstream
    val mem_out = Output(UInt(8.W)) // store the run's length using 8-bit runs (up to 255 consecutive same bits)
    val mem_addr = Output(UInt(mem_addr_length.W)) // memory position that the module wants to access (store/load)
    val writeEn = Output(Bool()) // signifies that there are data to be written in the memory
    val ready = Output(Bool()) // signifies that the process is over
  })
```

*Module function:* Compress the contents of the memory

```
Memory contents (IN)
|11101111|11111111|11111111|11111111|10111110|00000000|00111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111111|11111100|

Memory contents (OUT)
|00000011|00000001|00011101|00000001|00000101|00001011|00111000|00000010|
|   4x1  |   1x0  |  29x1  |   1x0  |   5x1  |  11x0  |  56x1  |   2x0  |
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide what you would like the input and output of this module to be. For example, is this a module that takes a single UInt or a Vec of them, or possibly runs through memory. What specifically would you like it to return. I suspect that what you want will be a good case for using Scala collection methods to generate what you want.

Comment: @ChickMarkley I have add some more information about the module's function.

Comment: Your edits have made the problem much clearer. I will take a look at a general solution tonight, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to input in(x) where x is a number defined in my state machine?

You can bit extract using registers/wires in your design. For example, each `is` in the state machine:

```
  is(step7) {
    current_bit := in(1)
    next_bit := in(0)
    // code here ...
  }
```

can be folded into something like

```
current_bit := in(state)
next_bit := in(state - 1.U)
```

(Subject to sorting out some details)

Another thing I would consider is using more aggregates. I don't entirely understand the memory interface, but one could express one as something like:

```
val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val mem = new Bundle {
    val addr = Output(UInt(mem_addr_length.W))
    val dataIn = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val dataOut = Output(UInt(8.W))
    val writeEn = Output(Bool())
  }
})
```

It is also generally easier to use some form of Decoupled (ie. ready-valid) design. For example in this case, I would probably have an outer module to interface with the memory (like the Module I/O in your edit), and an inner module to do just the encoding. eg.

```
val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val in = Decoupled(UInt(8.W)) // note Decoupled is defined in chisel3.util._
  val out = Decoupled(UInt(8.W))
})
```

Decoupled frequently helps reduce a problem size

Depending on your resource vs. latency constraints, you could also think about encoding multiple bits of the input per cycle. That is the kind of thing that can provide an interesting problem when writing a generator.

One could think about this encoding as essentially a truth table that could be implemented as a ROM. There are several dimensions you can parameterize it by, including max number of bits encoded per cycle as well as max number of encoded runs per cycle (although I suspect that with a single byte-per cycle memory interface there's no reason to make that larger than 1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is my first design with chisel and the second ever hardware design, so I am sure it would have some coding flaws.

I understand your idea and I think I like it. My alternative was to use a Mux1H to use the same state for each comparison. It is like a FSM in another FSM. 

The module is part of a bigger design, so I cannot spend more time thinking about it. BUT it is very challenging to make it work in one cycle. I was thinking to use a structure similar to leading zeros but I think I will come back later to think it over.